# How do I clear ONLY the *search history* in firefox 3?

Tags: firefox

The answers I have found tells you how to delete the search history AND to clear the forms, but I don't want that:

"Open the Mozilla Firefox browser, select "Tools" in the upper left-hand menu and select the "Clear Recent History" option. Tick the "Form & Search History" box and click the "Clear Now" button to delete Firefox's search history. Please note that you cannot undo this action."

I want to clear ONLY the *search history*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up in the right hand corner, where the Google (and others) search bar is, right-click on that and click "Clear Search History".

Hope this helps.

Comment: That kinda worked. However, it seems that I have to clear also the forms.

Comment: That will only clear the search history for the Google (or whatever search engine selected) in Firefox. I dont think it will clear search history at Google.com (or bing or whatever), just the browser search bar.

Are you trying to clear all search history in your browser (be it search bar or google.com?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question right but I find [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER) useful for it. You can set it up as you wish:
[image]